# Is there an easy way to skip episode intros in Netflix?

Tags: netflix

Problem: when watching episodes back-to-back, sitting through the intro/theme for a show is annoying. Especially for shows that I've watched many times before, like The Office.

Request: a simple and dependable way to skip the intro. Something like pressing 1, 2, or 3 while watching a video on YouTube to jump to the 10%, 20%, or 30% point of the video is what I have in mind.

Comment: I know that if you binge-watch TV through a Netflix mobile app, this is actually a built-in function (that I personally would like to be able to turn off). Anything at the very beginning of an episode that isn't the "meat" of the episode—recaps, themes/intros, etc.—are skipped. Bear in mind that if an episode has a cold open before a regular intro, it won't automatically skip anything (except prior recaps), as the cold open is part of the episode.

Comment: @SightSpirit Interesting. I'm told something like that happens on XBox as well. It's a bit frustrating that the experience varies from one platform to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lately, after coincidentally binge watching "The Office" (I'm not kidding!) once again, for the 4th time in a row (I don't think you need to that many times though) a little <kbd>Skip Intro</kbd> button showed up at the beginning of the theme song and at the end of the cold open. Click that to skip to the beginning of the content.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: YESSS!!! Finally!